# Закрыть определенные вкладки Firefox

Tags: firefox

подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли расширения или консольная команда, которая закроет все вкладки браузера с одинаковым заголовком?

Например: открыто 100 вкладок, 70 из них имеют название "Not Found | 404" (ответ сервера 200) и их нужно закрыть. Перебирать вручную муторно и долго.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы закрыть вкладку через js используйте `window.close()`, чтобы получить имя заголовка - `document.title`. Таким образом, просто проверив заголовок - закрыть вкладку.

```
if (document.title == 'Not Found | 404') window.close()
```

Теперь это дело нужно запихать в userScript. Для FireFox используйте GreaseMonkey. С его помощью при открытии вкладки проверится заголовок и если нужно закроется, затем сразу проверится следующая открывшаяся вкладка и т.д. Правда, если вкладку закрывать не нужно - придётся руками переключить :)

Comment: Спасибо, все отлично работает